# Is that possible to execute or call script PHP on rails?

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, view

I'd like to use Access analyzer 'TraceWatch' (http://www.tracewatch.com/ )
To use it I have 2 options.

1. Paste code in view and call PHP
2. Paste code in view and call JavaScript

People rarely turns off JavasScript.
But I'd like to choose 1st option to use PHP just in case.

I tried to paste this tomy rail's views/layouts/application.html.erb. 
It renders but it seems not calling PHP. Because it doesn't remain log.
Why? Is there any solution?

```
<head>
.
.
.

<?php
include_once $_SERVER[ 'DOCUMENT_ROOT' ].'/twatch/api/LogRequest.php';
twatchLogRequest();
?>

.
.
.
</head>
```

Comment: No, you can't just paste PHP code into a Rails view. The PHP script is meant for PHP applications. You have a Rails app, so use the javascript version.

Comment: @Micha Thank!! Okay! What would you think how many percent of people are turning off their Javascript??

Comment: Less than 1%. Most websites these days don't even work when javascript is turned off. Besides why would anyone *want* to turn off javascript? I don't see a reason for it.

Comment: Not sure what this script does exactly, but since there's a js implementation as well as a php implementation, you may well have a look how easy it is to port either one of the two to rails.

Comment: Thanks guys! I decided to use javascript then.